# VS code how to merge two files of which are in the same project

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS code we have the option to compare 2 files beloging to same project/branch. But I do not see option to merge?

Is there any suggested extension which would help me do this?

Comment: there are a lot of 2 or 3 way merge tools you can use

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To merge two branches say `main` and `develop`, you want to merge `develop` into `main`; you have to commit all changes on both branches. Then you have to checkout the `main` branch and then only you can merge another branch (here `develop`) into it.

There's a handy plugin for managing it at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens

Or you can use external git GUI tools like SourceTree or Github Desktop.

[image: Here is a sample]